# Couldn't resolve FqName com.google.protobuf.kotlin.ProtoDslMarker for Anvil

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, anvil

Adding all the protobuf dependencies and created proto file. Once trying to build the project seeing this error:

> com.squareup.anvil.compiler.api.AnvilCompilationException: Back-end
> (JVM) Internal error: Couldn't resolve FqName
> com.google.protobuf.kotlin.ProtoDslMarker for Psi element:
> com.google.protobuf.kotlin.ProtoDslMarker

I already created an issue in github https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/14160